# Can bootstrapping be applied to obtain CI for slope of trend of time series?

Tags: bootstrap, trend

I am trying to determine the confidence bound and significance for linear trend in temperature time series (january average values over 30 years). Is it possible to apply pairwise (temperature-year) block bootstrap for trend's slope (such that it preserves dependence) and obtain the confidence bound? I have found articles which have applied this for mean and correlation but I am confused whether this can be applied for slope as the order affects the value of slope unlike mean and correlation. Also, if this is possible, how to proceed with double bootstrap for improving the coverage accuracy?